# Fix JSON Formatting with jq

Tags: json, formatting, jq

Given an invalid JSON string such as: `{ foo: bar }` is it possible to get `jq` to process and format correctly as `{ "foo": "bar" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, or at least not without complex programming, though jq can handle objects with unquoted key names, e.g. `{foo: "bar"}`. (Hint: read the quasi-JSON as a jq program.)

The [jq FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ), however, does have a section giving details about a number of command-line tools that can be recommended for this kind of task, e.g. any-json and hjson.  That page provides links as well.